# Wide tiles for Windows Phone 7.8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm making a small application and I ran into a problem, I would like my app to have three tiles sizes. Right now I have only the two square sizes. How would I go about making the double wide title in Windows Phone 7.8?

Comment: Using the Mangopollo library makes things easier... http://mangopollo.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

A good example is provided here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720574(v=vs.105).aspx

The secret is to use feature detection and then set

WideBackgroundImage
WideBackBackgroundImage
WideBackContent